# Masking a UIImage twice results in an empty image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage

I'm creating a masked image using CGImageMaskCreate which works fine the first time it's called. However, when the same function is called a second time from drawRect the masked image created is empty.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{    
UIImage *maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"]; //This will be replaced    
UIImage *maskedImage = [self maskImage:_selectedImage withMask:maskImage];    
_selectedImage = maskedImage;    
[_selectedImage drawInRect:rect];                      
}

- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {   
    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;
    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);
    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
    NSLog(@"    MASK >> RETURNING %@ %f %f", 
           result.description, result.size.width, result.size.height);
return result;
}
```

After draw rect has run three times the output of the log is

```
MASK >> RETURNING UIImage: 0x903d720 320.000000 480.000000
MASK >> RETURNING UIImage: 0x73660c0 0.000000 0.000000
MASK >> RETURNING UIImage: 0x90f7390 0.000000 0.000000
```

So it seems like the masked image is empty after being called a second time.

Help would be great, this is my first app for IOS so maybe it's something obvious.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm seeing the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is your program logic:

At first, `_selectedImage` is empty. Thus, the mask creates a circle.

Now your `_selectedImage` already contains the circle. So the second time your circle will get zeroed out by the mask.

*--> Expected behavior*. If you did not expect that, maybe you want to read up on the Core Graphics masking functions.